# Convert now() to specific format in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do I convert now() to something like "November 21st, 2013"? I've looked into stuff like datepart and format but I can't find this translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print ConvertTodate(#12/13/2012#)
    Debug.Print ConvertTodate(#12/12/2012#)
    Debug.Print ConvertTodate(#12/14/2012#)
    Debug.Print ConvertTodate(#12/23/2012#)
    Debug.Print ConvertTodate(Now)
End Sub

Function ConvertTodate(d As Date) As String
    Dim suff As String
    Dim dt As String

    dt = Format(d, "mmmm dd, yyyy")

    Select Case Day(d)
        Case 0 To 10, 20 To 31
            Select Case Right(Day(d), 1)
                Case 1: suff = "st,"
                Case 2: suff = "nd,"
                Case 3: suff = "rd,"
                Case 0, 4 To 9: suff = "th,"
            End Select
        Case 11 To 20: suff = "th,"
    End Select

    ConvertTodate = Replace(dt, Day(d) & ",", Day(d) & suff)
End Function
```

[image]

**Note**: Based on your regional setting, you might have to use something else instead of a comma.

Comment: `Nice @SiddharthRout :-) Brain-running this seemed to give good results but I had to run it literally to see why it's wrong :-) –  Jean-François Corbett 3 mins ago` @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Sorry had to port the comment here as that post got deleted. Trust me you wouldn't want to know how embarrassed I felt when I realized my earlier code failed or #12/12/2012# :P Had no option but to take the answer down and re-work on it!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  I ran this in the VBA Immediate Window.

```
?Format(Now(),"mmmm dd, yyyy")
November 21, 2013
```

Comment: I had that too but couldn't get the "st" and "nd" and "rd" and "th"s to show up